# Is it possible to access appsetting/connection string values outside of Azure Functions v2 functions?

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, configuration, azure-functions, appsettings

In a nutshell, I'm trying to access the appsetting values in an Azure Function from helper classes outside of the function.  I have many child helper classes that are accessing appsettings directly.  This wasn't an issue with Azure Functions v1 since it used ConfigurationManager and I was able to simply create a helper class that used it to retrieve the appsetting/connection string values.  Can this be done with the same ease as Azure Functions v2?  If so, how? And examples please!

I would like to be able to somehow register ConfigurationBuilder and then inject it into the constructor of another class so that I could retrieve appsetting values. I've seen all kinds of examples of how to set this up and use it right away directly from the entry point (Run).  But I haven't found any legit examples on how to set it up in a "startup" class and then be able to inject it into any class constructor throughout the project.

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

I would appreciate an example in c# of how to register this with the dependency injection (can it be used with .net framework directly or does it need some third party DI library like Unity?) and then inject it in some other class constructor.

Comment: depend on what version of azure functions you are using.

Comment: You seem to be confusing some of the technologies/platforms.

Comment: I would also suggest you not inject the configuration builder or built configuration. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: @Nikosi:  This is for Azure Function v2.

Comment: @Nikosi:  It's not an XY problem.  The problem is obvious:  How do you retrieve appsetting values from the "AppSettings" (which could be from local.settings.json or AppSettings in Azure) from classes outside of the one that contains the "Run" entry point?

Comment: Is your function static or are you using instance injection?

Comment: I stated XY because azure function to my knowledge does not use Startup.

Comment: The function is static.  I'm just trying to access appsettings from helper classes that are outside of that function.

Comment: Right. This is way bigger than what you have shown so far. I want to help. The question in its current state however does not provided enough context to clarify the current situation. As I stated there are multiple approaches but it depends on the function and how it was constructed

Comment: So are you saying that Microsoft just over complicated it with version 2?  With version 1, you could simply create a helper class that handles pulling in appsettings with the ConfigurationManager and be done with it.

Comment: @TheDude all you need is to access a environment variable in a helper class the goes side by functions right ?

Comment: @HariHaran:  I'm just trying to access AppSettings or local.settings.json (when running locally) from helper classes outside of the main function class.  And for the record, I've already tried this:  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key_here").  It doesn't seem to work with Azure Functions v2.

Comment: @TheDude `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` works for me, can you show the local.settings.json ? Can you also double check the function runtime version